# Excel Formula to convert comma separated column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have the following list of two columns, which contains view names in column A and tables name seperated by comma in column B.

[image]

Want to convert the same in below format:

[image]

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Please add the code or formulas you have tried (even if they have given unsatisfactory results).  And also your version of Excel, since solutions may vary depending on version.

Comment: If you got Excel 365 maybe you can do this using MATCH with wildcards and FILTER and TEXTJOIN. Also, remember Excel is not the same as Google Sheets, so please use the right tag

Answer (score 1):

in GS use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:A&"×"&SPLIT(B1:B, ",")), "×")), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), 
 " ", "×", 1), "×")), " ", ", "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Only with Excel365

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER($A$1:$A$2;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D6;$B$1:$B$2))))
```